# MySQL Select multiple distinct

Tags: mysql

I have one table which holds lots of records. Its for an auction site. This table can have multiple user_id which can be the same and multiple auction_id which can be the same.

I am trying to write a script that sends an email once to each user that has placed a bid. If a user places say 10 bids on the same auction, I only want the email to be sent once per user per auction, per bid.

How would I do this with distinct over 2 fields? The user_id field and the auction_listing field? I will also need to have a WHERE clause so I only select records of auctions that have less than 24 hours to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your table schema it is hard to answer to answer you question.

In general if you do a [GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) user_id in the end one user will only appear once in your query results

Comment: Hi thanks. I am actually selecting all auctions with less than 24 hours first and then have a nested select query to get the bidders so the group worked...I should have thought about that!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.user_id, b.auction_listing
FROM AuctionBids b
JOIN Auctions a USING (auction_listing)
WHERE a.end_datetime < NOW() + INTERVAL 24 hour
```

Or

```
SELECT b.user_id, b.auction_listing
FROM AuctionBids b
JOIN Auctions a USING (auction_listing)
WHERE a.end_datetime < NOW() + INTERVAL 24 hour
GROUP BY b.user_id, b.auction_listing
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. It turned out a lot easier than I thought. I should have taken 10 more min to think about it.